# Как сохранить редактирование?

Tags: html, php

Прикрутил на страничку WysiBB редактор, как реализовать две кнопки - редактировать и сохранить, при нажатии на которые будет редактироваться и
сохранятся файл, к примеру 123.txt, (на данный момент получилось только
сделать кнопку редактировать при нажатии на которую открывается редактор). Но я не могу понять, как его связать с 123.txt и сохранить изменения.

Вот код:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Просто Страничка ))</title>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="wysibb/jquery.wysibb.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wysibb/theme/default/wbbtheme.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function exampleClickToEdit()
{
$('#wbbeditor').wysibb({ focus: true });
}
function exampleClickToSave()
{
// save content if you need
var html = $('#wbbeditor').getCode();
// destroy editor
$('#wbbeditor').destroyEditor();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>WysiBB WYSIWYG</h2>
<div id="wbbeditor">
888888888
</div>
<p align="center" style="width:25%; float:center;">
<button class="btn" onclick="exampleClickToEdit();">Edit</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="exampleClickToSave();">Save</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

куски кода нашел [тут](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/click-to-edit/)

Или к примеру как повесить этот же редактор на страницу, и чтобы любой кто зайдёт мог только дополнять комментарии/текст (может такое легче реализовать) с теми же кнопками ((

Comment: в exampleClickToSave добавьте ajax который пошлет данные из  переменной html на сервер.

Comment: а именно как ето сделать ? сам код ? бо я сам в етом ни бум бум голова ), а повашему совету толком ничего не нашел, а там где что то написано про ети аяксы голова плавится.

Comment: @MERCURY если вы не бум-бум, то зачем вы беретесь за это дело ? Я например не отличаюсь геркулесовой силой и в грузчики не иду.

Comment: @eicto а я например не программист а просто нужно сделать такую страничку, и я не намерен углубляться в изучение всего этого у меня как и у вас и у других людей своя сфера деятельности и есть чем занятся

Comment: @MERCURY, если у вас своя сфера деятельности, то наймите профессионала, а не стройте из себя жертву. Тут люди ищут подсказку, а не оставляют заказы.

Comment: @MERCURY, если вы не намерены углубляться, то этот форум не для вас, проще говоря - вам на фриланс.

Answer (score 4):

Доброго дня, [[@MERCURY](/users/12283/mercury)](/users/12283/mercury)!

Проведу вам небольшую инструкцию, которая, надеюсь, вам поможет в ваших начинаниях!)

Итак, давайте разберемся сначала с нашим интерфейсом. У вас есть 2 кнопки - одна активирует редактор, а другая сначала получает html содержимое редактора. Ясен пень, ваш пример не работает в причину того, что стили и скрипт редактора у вас на сайте. Я про это:

```
<script src="wysibb/jquery.wysibb.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="wysibb/theme/default/wbbtheme.css" type="text/css" />
```

Окей, это не проблема, заходим на сайт плагина (http://www.wysibb.com), получаем абсолютные ссылки до стилей и скриптов. Попутно смотрим документацию и видим, что методов `getCode()` и `destroyEditor()` нет, а вместо них присутствуют `htmlcode()` и `destroy()` соответственно. Заменяем методы.

В вашем вопросе говорится о том, что данные должны сохраняться в файле. Уважаемый [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) предложил передавать данные из редактора скрипту на сайте через функцию [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Выстраивается такая логика: получаем данные из формы и отправляем их скрипту на сайте:

```
function exampleClickToSave() {
    // save content if you need
    var html = $('#wbbeditor').htmlcode(); 
    // destroy editor
    $('#wbbeditor').destroy();
    //
    $.ajax({
        'url':'save_page.php', // ссылка на скрипт
        'type':'POST', // тип запроса
        'data': {'dataSave': html}, // передаваемые данные скрипту

        'success': function(data) { //  ну и функция, которая будет уведомлять нас о том, что файл сохранился
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Хорошо, с интерфейсом закончили. Теперь перейдем к скрипту сохранения данных в файл. У вас, как я вижу по тегам, используется php.

Самый простой и удобный способ сохранить данные в файл, это [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/fwrite)

```
$filename = '123.txt'; // название файла
$somecontent = $_POST['dataSave']; // с этим я думаю понятно

// Вначале давайте убедимся, что файл существует и доступен для записи.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // В нашем примере мы открываем $filename в режиме "перезапись файла".
    // Таким образом
    // наш $somecontent перезапишет файл при использовании fwrite().
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
         echo "Не могу открыть файл ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // Записываем $somecontent в наш открытый файл.
    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Не могу произвести запись в файл ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Ура! Записали ($somecontent) в файл ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} 
else {
    echo "Файл $filename недоступен для записи";
}
```

Вот и всё, вам остается правильно выполнить мои инструкции и у вас будет всё работать!

Хорошего дня, задавайте свои вопросы!)

Comment: теперь я в обще не въезжаю что куда О_о

Comment: @MERCURY, учитесь, учитесь, и ещё раз учитесь) нужны знания, и просто всё будет.

Comment: и все таки может кто то нормально объяснить ???

Comment: @MERCURY еще раз прочтите и попробуйте сделать по моим инструкциям то, что вы хотели. Я в ответе всё "разжевал". Первые 3 абзаца можете отбросить (но я думаю, что обновление скрипта не будет лишним).

Comment: мда... помогли спасибо, кулацкеры ёпт...

Comment: @MERCURY тут понимать и нечего, вам нужно лишь в интерфейсе (в файле, где у вас редактор) заменить функцию exampleClickToSave() на ту, что у меня указана. И рядом создать файл с названием save_page.php и закинуть туда php код, что указан у меня.

Comment: @MERCURY "мда... помогли, спасибо...", что? что? что?

Comment: @lampa - о теперь дошло и вроде бы разобрался, покопав про это php нашел в документации $file_get_contents() и $file_put_contents(), переделал код = в файл сохраняет но не через редактор, а то что укажешь в save_page.php, буду пилить дальше. Спасибо !